# spring read properties file from different maven module

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, properties

```
demo-parent:
  --web
    --src
      --main
        --java
          --Application.java
        --resources
          --application.yml
          --application-mysql.yml
   --service
   --common
     --src
       --main
         --java
           --Config.java
         --resources
           --core-application.yml
```

there are some `spring properties` in `core-application` like `spring.kafka.properties.bootstrap.servers`. How can I get them in my *web module*?

I have an error `FileNotFoundException: class path resource [core-application.yml] cannot be opened because it does not exist` now.

Comment: If the common module is available as a dependency it is available and can be loaded. So it must be either not available as a dependency, or you are loading it in the wrong way.

Comment: @M.Deinum no, I can load module. But I can not get spring properties in loaded module.

Comment: As I stated it either isn't available as a module on the classpath **or** you are loading it wrong. So please show how you are doing things in the classpath (adding the module etc.) and how you are loading it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@PropertySource` annotation is repeatable according to Java 8 conventions. Therefore, if we're using Java 8 or higher, we can use this annotation to define multiple property locations:

```
@PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties")
@PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}



@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

Refer this article, https://www.baeldung.com/properties-with-spring